# Deduplicate large amount of data?

Tags: c#, collections, large-files

We have a file that contains hundreds of millions to billions of urls.

I would like to dedupe the urls with c#, but putting it into a `HashSet` collection or the like throws an `OutOfMemoryException` pretty quickly.

If I stream it, I could avoid the memory problem, but I'd need to maintain some state in a collection, which I would imagine would also cause a memory problem.

How can I quickly deduplicate this data using c# without running into memory issues?  I'm trying to avoid bulk-loading this into a database just to pull it back out again, and keep everything local to the machine.

I don't care about the OutOfMemoryException; I'm just explaining why that won't work.  I want to dedupe.

For a bit more context, we ship this file to a big data vendor who runs analytics on it, and they charge us by the amount of data they process.  Our systems administration group doesn't like the idea of setting up a db for what is ultimately a lot of temp data, and have asked us, "can't you just do it in code?"  I need to give it a shot.

Comment: Calculate a hash, store the hash? How quickly would you run into duplicates? No need then to save every single url, for the rest I guess using the correct tools for the task at hand, if a db can do it, then why not?

Comment: Did you thought about a divide and conquer approach to reduce the URLs step by step?

Comment: @Icepickle, I don't have metrics on this file at this time, but due to the nature of the data I expect we would have a large number of dupes, probably over 20%

Comment: If you expect to have lots of duplicates, Another option could be to do a first pass using Bloom Filter to reduce the size of the collection

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg you mean like some kind of binary search operation?

Comment: No, I meant dividing the whole block into multiple blocks, removing the duplicates and combine blocks together. But I think with 'only' 20% of duplicates the approach is not going to work very good.

Comment: What kind of file are we talking about here?  If you have a billion characters at two bytes each, it would be 2 GB.  A billion URLs at about 30 chars each isn't going to fit into memory, even if 20% of them are eliminated...  I would try splitting the file into many, many files, and then looping through them one at a time, inserting them into SQL Server if they don't already exist or something like that.  A flat file is not the best storage option for a 30-60 GB of data...

Comment: @Icepickle, That's not at all a duplicate.  I don't care about the OutOfMemoryException.  I want to dedupe.

Comment: Btw, which .net version are you looking at?

Comment: @Icepickle I'm in 4.5.2, but at the end of the day I don't feel that loading the collection into memory is what I want to do anyway.  I'm looking for some sort of algorithmic approach to manage this data stream to remove dupes.  (plus the machine this will be on only has 8gb ram)

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg so you mean like some file-based shell sort, maybe?

Comment: Yeah basically something like this @JeremyHolovacs

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg it's an interesting idea; I'll see how feasible it is.  Thanks!

Comment: Because most disks can't write to more than one file at a time, and finding each file on the disk has big overhead, the files have to be spread on separate disks/machines for better parallelized performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go over the things that make a URL unique. Much like the answer from [wezten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44833745/3231537), I think splitting the data is a good idea, however, you can shorten your path quite a lot by dividing the data in smaller files, like:

- domain of the url
- length of the url
- first and last char of the url

So the flow of the program would be like (pseudo code, just thinking about it):

```
while (url = largeFile.ReadLine()) {
    string directory = GetDirectoryForUrl( url );
    int wordLength = url.Length;
    string filename = url[0] + url[1];
    string fullName = Path.Combine( directory, wordLength.ToString(), fileName);

    var set = LoadSet( fullName );
    if (!set.Contains(url)) {
        AppendToFile( fullName, url );
    }
}
```

Then for the sub methods, something like

```
string GetDirectoryForUrl( string url ) {
    return GetDomain(url);
}

ISet<string> LoadSet( string fullName ) {
    // check if directories exists...
    if (!File.Exists( fullName )) { 
        return new HashSet<string>();
    }
    // load the hashset based on the file
}

void AppendToFile(string fullName, string url) {
    // add or create the file (check if directories exist)
}
```

This would of course create many many smaller files, but it would have the advantage that you are only checking small subsets of the data (though to be frank, I don't have a clue how your data looks, maybe only some characters differ)

The advantage here is that you could subdivide the data by criteria that you are aware of, and that you could tweak it in time

Didn't have time to create the full code (but since you are mainly looking for an algorithm :))

**update**

I created a small console program which both creates a file to test with, and then creates an analysis of the big file. Here is the code

The test in question generates around 1 million urls, but with such a limited random set of data, there are probably lots more duplicates than 20 % as you described your data to look like.

The analysis itself on my machine took around 26 minutes to complete, I cannot estimate if this time is appropriate, as I didn't test any other ways to write it.

The code changed a bit from my initial setup in so far that I used parts of the url for my directory structure. So far, with the dataset used, I didn't see a slowdown near the end of the program, though I also have to mention that Comodo kept my program in a sandbox.

Assembling all that data back to 1 large file is also not implemented, though, I don't really see any big problems there.

*Classes needed for running the program*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace analyzeduplicates {
  public interface IFileAnalyzer {
    IStringToDirectoryHelper StringToDirectoryHelper { set; }
    ISetFileHelper SetFileLoader { set; }
    void Analyze( string targetFile, string targetDirectory );
  }

  public interface IStringToDirectoryHelper {
    string[] GetPathFromString( string value );
  }

  public class StringToDirectoryHelper : IStringToDirectoryHelper {
    public string[] GetPathFromString( string value ) {
      string item = value.Trim();
      return item
        .Trim()
        .Split( new[] { "\\", "/", ":", "@", "%", ":", "?", "&", ";", "." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
        .Take( 3 )
        .Concat(new string[] { item.Length.ToString(), item[0].ToString() + item[value.Length-1].ToString() } )
        .ToArray();
    }
  }

  public interface ISetFileHelper {
    IReadOnlyCollection<string> GetSetFromFile( string path );
    void AddToSetFile( string path, string value );
  }

  public class SetFileHelper : ISetFileHelper {
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> GetSetFromFile( string path ) {
      if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))) {
        return new List<string>();
      }
      if (!File.Exists(path)) {
        return new List<string>();
      }
      return File.ReadAllLines( path );
    }

    public void AddToSetFile( string path, string value) {
      if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory( Path.GetDirectoryName( path ) );
      }
      File.AppendAllLines( path, new string[] { value } );
    }
  }

  public class FileAnalyzer: IFileAnalyzer {
    public IStringToDirectoryHelper StringToDirectoryHelper { get; set; }
    public ISetFileHelper SetFileLoader { get; set; }

    public FileAnalyzer() {

    }

    public FileAnalyzer(
      IStringToDirectoryHelper stringToDirectoryHelper, 
      ISetFileHelper setFileLoader) : this() {
      StringToDirectoryHelper = stringToDirectoryHelper;
      SetFileLoader = setFileLoader;
    }

    private void EnsureParametersSet() {
      if (StringToDirectoryHelper == null) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException( $"Cannot start analyzing without {nameof(StringToDirectoryHelper)}" );
      }
      if (SetFileLoader == null) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException( $"Cannot start analyzing without {nameof( SetFileLoader )}" );
      }
    }

    public void Analyze( string targetFile, string targetDirectory ) {
      EnsureParametersSet();
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(targetFile, true)) {
        long count = 0;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
          if (count % 1000 == 0) {
            Console.WriteLine( $"Analyzing line {count}-{count + 1000}" );
          }
          count++;
          string line = reader.ReadLine();
          if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) {
            // nothing meaningfull can be done
            continue;
          }
          var path = StringToDirectoryHelper.GetPathFromString( line );
          string targetPath = Path.Combine( new[] { targetDirectory }.Concat( path ).ToArray() );
          var set = SetFileLoader.GetSetFromFile( targetPath );
          if (set.Contains(line)) {
            // duplicate, don't care for it
            continue;
          }
          SetFileLoader.AddToSetFile( targetPath, line );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Console program itself*

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace analyzeduplicates {
  class Program {

    static void Main( string[] args ) {
      string targetFile = Path.Combine( Environment.CurrentDirectory, "source.txt" );
      if (File.Exists(targetFile)) {
        File.Delete( targetFile );
      }
      if ( !File.Exists( targetFile ) ) {
        Console.WriteLine( "Generating extensive list of urls" );
        Stopwatch generateWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        GenerateList( targetFile );
        generateWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine( "Generating took {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", generateWatch.Elapsed );
      }
      Console.WriteLine( "Analyzing file" );
      Stopwatch analyzeWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      IFileAnalyzer analyzer = new FileAnalyzer(new StringToDirectoryHelper(), new SetFileHelper());
      analyzer.Analyze( targetFile, Environment.CurrentDirectory );
      analyzeWatch.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine( "Analyzing took {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", analyzeWatch.Elapsed );
      Console.WriteLine( "done, press enter to clean up" );
      Console.ReadLine();
      File.Delete( targetFile );
      foreach (var dir in Directory.GetDirectories( Environment.CurrentDirectory )) {
        Directory.Delete( dir, true );
      }
      Console.WriteLine( "Cleanup completed, press enter to exit" );
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void GenerateList( string targetFile ) {
      string[] domains = new[] {
        "www.google.com",
        "www.google.de",
        "www.google.ca",
        "www.google.uk",
        "www.google.co.uk",
        "www.google.nl",
        "www.google.be",
        "www.google.fr",
        "www.google.sa",
        "www.google.me",
        "www.youtube.com",
        "www.youtube.de",
        "www.youtube.ca",
        "www.youtube.uk",
        "www.youtube.co.uk",
        "www.youtube.nl",
        "www.youtube.be",
        "www.youtube.fr",
        "www.youtube.sa",
        "www.youtube.me"
      };
      string[] paths = new[] {
        "search","indicate", "test", "generate", "bla", "bolognes", "macaroni", "part", "of", "web", "site", "index", "main", "nav"
      };
      string[] extensions = new[] {
        "", ".html", ".php", ".aspx", ".aspx", "htm"
      };
      string[] query = new[] {
        "", "?s=test", "?s=query&b=boloni", "?isgreat", "#home", "#main", "#nav"
      };
      string[] protocols = new[] {
        "http://", "https://", "ftp://", "ftps://"
      };
      using (var writer = new StreamWriter(targetFile)) {
        var rnd = new Random();
        for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
          int pathLength = rnd.Next( 5 );
          string path = "/";
          if (pathLength > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j< pathLength; j++ ) {
              path += paths[rnd.Next( paths.Length )] + "/";
            }
          }
          writer.WriteLine( "{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", protocols[rnd.Next( protocols.Length )], domains[rnd.Next(domains.Length)], path, paths[rnd.Next(paths.Length)], extensions[rnd.Next(extensions.Length)], query[rnd.Next(query.Length)] );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure if the full answer now is not a little bit to big, but I thought I could share it. I don't have a clue how the program would perform on a dataset as large as the one you described, I would be interested in getting a time in case it was working for you :)

Comment: Hmm... the trick here would be managing the size of the directories.  Once you get over 2000 files/ directories in one place, Windows does funny things, performance-wise.  I'll see if I can't model this as well.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Sure, that is why you should be able to divide the data better than me, as I don't know how your data is looking. For example you could subdivide also by http / https. It's really hard to tell without knowing how the data is looking, I do think that this method would allow you to loop only once over all the items (except for reassembling it back into 1 big file). The question is ofcourse if you are then not the one doing the data analises :)

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I updated the answer with a basic implementation, the time it took for the 1 million lines size dataset was done before I added the length of the url to the directory structure, and I am curious how the test in progress will perform now :)

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs With the length in place, the test on the dataset took around 14 minutes, so definitely worth using it :)

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Thanks for accepting the answer, does that mean it worked? Do you have any statistics? :)

Comment: I did something "Inspired by your answer"... unfortunately it ran pretty slow, even on fast disk, to the point that we had more data before we finished processing, and it was a losing battle.  We ended up not deduping the data before sending it off and eating the extra cost.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a billion URLs, and you can hold a million in a hashset without memory issues.

Put the first million URLs in a hashset. Record the hashset size `s1`. Write them to a new file. Read the rest of the URLs, check each one against the hashset, and write them to the new file. You now know that the first `s1` URLs are unique.

Put the URLs from position `s1` to `s1 + 1m` of the new file in a new hashset. Record the size `s2`. Write the first `s1` URLs that you know are unique to a new file. Now write the hashset contents. Now read the rest of the URLs, checking them against the hashset. You now know that the first `s1 + s2` URLs are unique.

Put URLs from position `s1 + s2` to `s1 + s2 + 1m` in a new hashset. And so on, until you know they are all unique.

Comment: It seems a bit brute-forceish, but it seems like it should work.  I'll try it out.

Comment: It's much simpler than what I initially wrote - updated.